# Material UI Data Grid, customize the toolbar default slots with disableColumnMenu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

**Context**
I am using the Datagrid component from MUI library@6.9.1. I am using disableColumnMenu to show toolbar at the top of the table i.e. not on individual column.

```
 <DataGrid
      disableColumnMenu
      slots={ { toolbar: GridToolbar } }

         ...
  />
```

**What I need?**
I want to change the header name from ***COLUMNS*** -> MyColumn, ***Density*** -> MyDensity.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use **localeText** prop in DataGrid , like this :

```html
 <DataGrid
    disableColumnMenu
    slots={{ toolbar: GridToolbar }}
    localeText={{
       toolbarColumns: "MyColumns",
       toolbarFilters: "MyFilters",
       toolbarDensity: "MyDensity",
       toolbarExport: "MyExports",
     }}
  />
```